# Android: How to avoid overlapping of generated Textview on different position?

Tags: android, textview, android-relativelayout

I am working on generating different UI TextView onto the main layout programmatically and put into different position w.r.t different margins. When it comes to the implementation and testing, all textviews generated are overlapping. Would you please tell me what to put the textviews programmatically generated into different positions ?

The below is my method:

```
        setLabel(lblPairing , "PAIRING" , (int)(0.22*screenWidth), (int)(0.075*screenHeight) , ColorTool.changeTextColor("#e3e3e5"), 
                "fonts/TitilliumText22L003.otf" ,   screenWidth , mainCt , 40.0f );


    public void setLabel(AutoResizeTextView tv , String text , int xpos , int ypos,  int color, 
            String fontPath , int screenWidth , Context ctx , float size){

        Typeface myTypefaceX = Typeface.createFromAsset(ctx.getAssets(), fontPath ); 
        tv.setTypeface(myTypefaceX);
        tv.setTextColor(color);
        tv.setTextSize(size*screenWidth / 1080);
        tv.setText(text);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lp.setMargins(xpos, ypos, 0, 0);
        tv.setLayoutParams(lp);
        main.addView(tv);
        System.out.println("xpos " + xpos );
        System.out.println("ypos " + ypos);
}
```

The below is my layout.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/my_frame"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_areas"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/shaded_region"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/cover_1_d" />

    <com.adapter.AutoResizeTextView
        android:id="@+id/lblPairing"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="78dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Pairing"
        android:textColor="#fff" />
.....

</RelativeLayout>
```

Entire Activity Code

```
public class CoverActivity extends Activity 
implements View.OnTouchListener 
{

    /**
     * Create the view for the activity.
     *
     */

    private AutoResizeTextView lblPairing;
    private AutoResizeTextView lblCalibrate;
    private AutoResizeTextView lblFlight1;
    private AutoResizeTextView lblFlight2;
    private AutoResizeTextView lblBluetooth;
    private AutoResizeTextView lblBLEStatus;
    private AutoResizeTextView lblFirmW;
    private AutoResizeTextView lblFirmVersion;
    private AutoResizeTextView lblnameTitle;
    private AutoResizeTextView lblnameCustom;
    private String versionNum;
    private String nameDrone;
    private Display display ;
    private Point size;
    private int screenWidth;
    private int screenHeight;
    private RelativeLayout main;
    private Context mainCt;
    private ImageView iv;
    @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Remove title bar
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        //Remove notification bar
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);


        screenWidth= size.x;
        screenHeight = size.y;
        System.out.println("screenWidth " + screenWidth );
        System.out.println("screenHeight " + screenHeight);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cover);
        main  = (RelativeLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.my_frame);
        System.out.println("main " + main);

        mainCt = this.getApplicationContext();
        lblPairing = new AutoResizeTextView(this); 
                //new (AutoResizeTextView)findViewById(R.id.lblPairing);
        lblCalibrate= new AutoResizeTextView(this);  
        //(AutoResizeTextView)this.findViewById(R.id.lblCalibrate);
    /*  lblFlight1=   (AutoResizeTextView)this.findViewById(R.id.lblFlight1);
        lblFlight2=   (AutoResizeTextView)this.findViewById(R.id.lblFlight2);
        lblBluetooth=  (AutoResizeTextView)this.findViewById(R.id.lblBluetooth);   
        lblBLEStatus=   (AutoResizeTextView)this.findViewById(R.id.lblBLEStatus);
        lblFirmW=   (AutoResizeTextView)this.findViewById(R.id.lblFirmW); 
        lblFirmVersion=  (AutoResizeTextView)this.findViewById(R.id.lblFirmVersion);
        lblnameTitle=  (AutoResizeTextView)this.findViewById(R.id.lblnameTitle); 
        lblnameCustom=    (AutoResizeTextView)this.findViewById(R.id.lblnameCustom); */

        Typeface myTypefaceX = Typeface.createFromAsset(mainCt.getAssets(), "fonts/TitilliumText22L003.otf" ); //"fonts/TitilliumText22L003.otf");

        lblPairing.setTypeface(myTypefaceX);
        lblPairing.setTextColor(ColorTool.changeTextColor("#e3e3e5"));
        lblPairing.setTextSize(40.0f*screenWidth / 1080);
        lblPairing.setText("PAIRING");
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        //lp.setMargins(xpos, ypos, 0, 0);
        setMargins(lblPairing ,  (int)(0.22*screenWidth) , (int)(0.075*screenHeight)  , 0 , 0 );
        lblPairing.setLayoutParams(lp);
        main.addView(lblPairing , lp); 


        lblCalibrate.setTypeface(myTypefaceX);
        lblCalibrate.setTextColor(ColorTool.changeTextColor("#e3e3e5"));
        lblCalibrate.setTextSize(40.0f*screenWidth / 1080);
        lblCalibrate.setText("CALIBRATION");
        //lp.setMargins(xpos, ypos, 0, 0);
        setMargins(lblCalibrate ,  (int)(0.535*screenWidth) , (int)(0.12*screenHeight)  , 0 , 0 );
        lblCalibrate.setLayoutParams(lp);
        main.addView(lblCalibrate , lp); 
        //RelativeLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);

        /*setLabel(lblPairing , "PAIRING" , (int)(0.22*screenWidth), (int)(0.075*screenHeight) , ColorTool.changeTextColor("#e3e3e5"), 
                "fonts/TitilliumText22L003.otf" ,   screenWidth , mainCt , 40.0f );

        setLabel(lblCalibrate , "CALIBRATION" , (int)(0.535*screenWidth), (int)(0.12*screenHeight) , ColorTool.changeTextColor("#e3e3e5"), 
                "fonts/TitilliumText22L003.otf" ,   screenWidth , mainCt , 40.0f );

        setLabel(lblFlight1 , "GENERAL" , (int)(0.13*screenWidth), (int)(0.17*screenHeight) , ColorTool.changeTextColor("#e3e3e5"), 
                "fonts/TitilliumText22L003.otf" ,   screenWidth , mainCt , 40.0f );

        setLabel(lblFlight2 , "SETTINGS" , (int)(0.195*screenWidth), (int)(0.20*screenHeight) , ColorTool.changeTextColor("#e3e3e5"), 
                "fonts/TitilliumText22L003.otf" ,   screenWidth , mainCt , 40.0f );

        setLabel(lblBluetooth , "Bluetooth" , (int)(0.31*screenWidth), (int)(0.795*screenHeight) , ColorTool.changeTextColor("#e3e3e5"), 
                "fonts/TitilliumText22L003.otf" ,   screenWidth , mainCt , 20.0f );

        setLabel(lblBLEStatus , "Pending" , (int)(0.33*screenWidth), (int)(0.825*screenHeight) , ColorTool.changeTextColor("#e3e3e5"), 
                "fonts/TitilliumText22L003.otf" ,   screenWidth , mainCt , 20.0f );

        setLabel(lblFirmW , "Firmware Version" , (int)(0.34*screenWidth), (int)(0.87*screenHeight) , ColorTool.changeTextColor("#e3e3e5"), 
                "fonts/TitilliumText22L003.otf" ,   screenWidth , mainCt , 20.0f );

        setLabel(lblFirmVersion , "0.00" , (int)(0.78*screenWidth), (int)(0.87*screenHeight) , ColorTool.changeTextColor("#e3e3e5"), 
                "fonts/TitilliumText22L003.otf" ,   screenWidth , mainCt , 20.0f );

        setLabel(lblnameTitle , "Name" , (int)(0.03*screenWidth), (int)(0.88*screenHeight) , ColorTool.changeTextColor("#e3e3e5"), 
                "fonts/TitilliumText22L003.otf" ,   screenWidth , mainCt , 20.0f );

        setLabel(lblnameCustom , "Novax350" , (int)(0.03*screenWidth), (int)(0.93*screenHeight) , ColorTool.changeTextColor("#e3e3e5"), 
                "fonts/TitilliumText22L003.otf" ,   screenWidth , mainCt , 20.0f );
*/


        iv = (ImageView) findViewById (R.id.image);
        if (iv != null) {
            iv.setOnTouchListener(this);

        }

    }

    /**
     * Respond to the user touching the screen.
     * Change images to make things appear and disappear from the screen.
     *
     */    



    public void changeName(View v) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.showSoftInput(v, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
    }

    public static void setMargins (View v, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        if (v.getLayoutParams() instanceof ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) {
            ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams p = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
            p.setMargins(l, t, r, b);
            v.requestLayout();
        }
    }

    public void setLabel(TextView textview , String text , int xpos , int ypos,  int color, 
            String fontPath , int screenWidth , Context ctx , float size){

        Typeface myTypefaceX = Typeface.createFromAsset(ctx.getAssets(), fontPath ); //"fonts/TitilliumText22L003.otf");
        System.out.println("myTypefaceX " + myTypefaceX );
        System.out.println("tv " + textview );
        textview.setTypeface(myTypefaceX);
        textview.setTextColor(color);
        textview.setTextSize(size*screenWidth / 1080);
        textview.setText(text);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        //lp.setMargins(xpos, ypos, 0, 0);
        setMargins(textview , xpos , ypos , 0 , 0 );
        textview.setLayoutParams(lp);

        System.out.println("xpos " + xpos );
        System.out.println("ypos " + ypos);




        /*RelativeLayout.LayoutParams llp = new 
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        llp.setMargins(xpos, ypos, 0, 0); // llp.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
        Typeface myTypefaceX = Typeface.createFromAsset(ctx.getAssets(), fontPath ); //"fonts/TitilliumText22L003.otf");
        tv.setTypeface(myTypefaceX);
        tv.setTextColor(color);
        tv.setTextSize(size*screenWidth / 1080);
        tv.setText(text);
        tv.setLayoutParams(llp);*/
        //main.addView(tv);

    }




    public boolean onTouch (View v, MotionEvent ev) 
    {
        boolean handledHere = false;

        final int action = ev.getAction();

        final int evX = (int) ev.getX();
        final int evY = (int) ev.getY();
        int nextImage = -1;         // resource id of the next image to display

        // If we cannot find the imageView, return.
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById (R.id.image);
        if (imageView == null) return false;

        // When the action is Down, see if we should show the "pressed" image for the default image.
        // We do this when the default image is showing. That condition is detectable by looking at the
        // tag of the view. If it is null or contains the resource number of the default image, display the pressed image.
        Integer tagNum = (Integer) imageView.getTag ();
        int currentResource = (tagNum == null) ? R.drawable.cover_1_d : tagNum.intValue ();

        // Now that we know the current resource being displayed we can handle the DOWN and UP events.

        switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :
            if (currentResource == R.drawable.cover_1_d) {
                nextImage = R.drawable.cover_1_d;
                handledHere = true;
                /*
       } else if (currentResource != R.drawable.cover_1_d) {
         nextImage = R.drawable.cover_1_d;
         handledHere = true;
                 */
            } else handledHere = true;
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP :
            // On the UP, we do the click action.
            // The hidden image (image_areas) has three different hotspots on it.
            // The colors are red, blue, and yellow.
            // Use image_areas to determine which region the user touched.
            int touchColor = getHotspotColor (R.id.image_areas, evX, evY);

            // Compare the touchColor to the expected values. Switch to a different image, depending on what color was touched.
            // Note that we use a Color Tool object to test whether the observed color is close enough to the real color to
            // count as a match. We do this because colors on the screen do not match the map exactly because of scaling and
            // varying pixel density.
            ColorTool ct = new ColorTool ();
            int tolerance = 25;
            nextImage = R.drawable.cover_1_d;
            if (ct.closeMatch (Color.RED, touchColor, tolerance)) { 
                nextImage = R.drawable.cover_1_d;
                startActivity(new Intent().setClass(CoverActivity.this, PairingActivity.class).
                        setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
            }
            else if (ct.closeMatch (Color.BLUE, touchColor, tolerance)) {
                nextImage = R.drawable.cover_1_d;
                startActivity(new Intent().setClass(CoverActivity.this, SettingListHeaderActivity.class).
                        setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
            }
            else if (ct.closeMatch (Color.GREEN, touchColor, tolerance)) {
                nextImage = R.drawable.cover_1_d;
                startActivity(new Intent().setClass(CoverActivity.this, CalibrateSelectActivity.class).
                        setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
            }
            else if (ct.closeMatch (Color.WHITE, touchColor, tolerance)) nextImage = R.drawable.cover_1_d;

            // If the next image is the same as the last image, go back to the default.
            // toast ("Current image: " + currentResource + " next: " + nextImage);
            if (currentResource == nextImage) {
                nextImage = R.drawable.cover_1_d;
            } 
            handledHere = true; 
            break;

        default:
            handledHere = false;
        } // end switch

        if (handledHere) {

            if (nextImage > 0) {
                imageView.setImageResource (nextImage);
                imageView.setTag (nextImage);
            }
        }
        return handledHere;
    }   

    /**
     */
    // More methods

    /**
     * Get the color from the hotspot image at point x-y.
     * 
     */

    public Bitmap generateBM() {
        Bitmap result = null;

        return result;
    }
    public int getHotspotColor (int hotspotId, int x, int y) {
        ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById (hotspotId);
        if (img == null) {
            Log.d ("ImageAreasActivity", "Hot spot image not found");
            return 0;
        } else {
            img.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true); 
            Bitmap hotspots = Bitmap.createBitmap(img.getDrawingCache()); 
            if (hotspots == null) {
                Log.d ("ImageAreasActivity", "Hot spot bitmap was not created");
                return 0;
            } else {
                img.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
                return hotspots.getPixel(x, y);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Show a string on the screen via Toast.
     * 
     * @param msg String
     * @return void
     */

    public void toast (String msg)
    {
        Toast.makeText (getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show ();
    } // end toast

} // end class
```

Comment: Put complete code including layout xmls.

Comment: i have put the code , please check carefully

Comment: @RajuGujarati use `LinearLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout` as your all views are placed relatively with parent not with each other thats why it is overlapping

Comment: Which part to be modified as LinearLayout ?

Comment: It is because I want my textviews to be put in specific positions relative to the screen width and height , not aligning left or right to the another UI txtviews

Comment: can you post an image with the positions of this textviews?

Comment: RelativeLayout  change this to linear layout.

Comment: All items will becomes blank, I have tested. Would you please tell me more about the workings ?

Comment: please put entire activity code, its really hard to figure out by just seeing one api call.

Comment: entire activity code is put

Comment: alright let me figure it out, can you also put an screenshot of your issue?

Comment: And an example of the positions of the textviews?

Comment: yes yes yes yes yes ...